# Change FourierParameters in CUDAFourier

Tags: fourier-analysis, cudalink

`CUDAFourier` does not have option `FourierParameters`. I need to change its convention. It has default `{0,1}`. I need `{1,-1}` for signal processing. How can I change its convention or transform my data after `CUDAFourier` operation to get result in `{1,-1}` convention?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, as you say, `CUDAFourier[]` does not support the `FourierParameters` option, you will need to use `CUDAInverseFourier[]` instead and do a manual renormalization. Observe:

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]

BlockRandom[SeedRandom[0]; (* for reproducibility *)
            lst = RandomComplex[{-9, 9} (1 + I), 32]];

f1 = Sqrt[Length[lst]] CUDAInverseFourier[lst];

f2 = Fourier[lst, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];

Norm[f1 - f2, ∞]
   1.51772*10^-14
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast, thank you very much for help.